# Array Sort in JS

Tags: javascript

What's going on here?

```
var values = [10, 2, 1];
console.log(values.sort());
```

output:

> [1, 10, 2]

http://jsfiddle.net/A2vRt/

Comment: Spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11

Comment: @Rikonator That question is about a multidimensional array.

Comment: If you want to sort your array numerically, take a look at the accepted answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/sort-not-working-with-integers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript's array `sort()` function is doing [Lexicographic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) sorting. It is sorting based on the "string" value of each element. In that case, `1` is before `10` because although they have the same prefix, `1` is shorter. They are both before `2` because `1` is before `2` (i.e. it never even looks at the second character of the `10`).

You can also write your own "comparator" function to sort using whatever criteria you want. To sort numerically, try this:

```
var values = [10, 2, 1];
console.log(values.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b}));
```

For more details on Array sorting, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

And just for fun, a more complex example, sorting a complex object using different methods:

```
var people = [
    {
        name: "Bob",
        age: 42
    },
    {
        name: "Alan",
        age: 50
    },
    {
        name: "Charlie",
        age: "18"
    }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(people)); // Before sorting
people.sort(function(a,b) { // Sort by name
    if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
    else if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
    else return 0;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(people));
people.sort(function(a,b) { // Sort by age
    return a.age - b.age;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(people));
```

Answer (score 3):

Default sort order is alphabetic and ascending.When numbers are sorted alphabetically, "40" comes before "5".To perform a numeric sort, you must pass a function as an argument when calling the sort method you need a function that defines the sort order. four your case use  :

```
values.sort(function(a,b){return a-b})
```

Comment: The question was *"What's going on here?*". So what's going on and what does your answer do?

Comment: You should [edit] your answer and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript sort works alphabetically. So you have to provide your own sort function. The function should return + for greater, 0 for equal and - for lesser value. So for ascending order try this:

```
values.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
```